# how to go from using app.config of WCF binding and convert it to bind programmatically in correct manner

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap

I have the following binding which works fine when I create client.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="Assets_AssetsPort" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                    receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Mtom" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
                <binding name="AssetsPortBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                    receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://osi-tm/services/Assets" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="Assets_AssetsPort" contract="InterplayWS.AssetsPortType"
                name="AssetsPort" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

However now I need to configure this without any config file.  So I attempted to do the following:

```
    BasicHttpBinding basicBinding = new BasicHttpBinding()
    {
        MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647,
        MaxBufferPoolSize = 2147483647
    };
    basicBinding.MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Mtom;


    var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(String.Format("http://{0}/services/Assets?wsdl", Connection.InterplayHost)));

    var client = new AssetClient(basicBinding, endpoint);
```

When I run this up I get an error

```
<Exception>
<ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException, System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>Unrecognized message version.</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReceivedMessage.ReadStartEnvelope(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessage..ctor(IBufferedMessageData messageData, RecycledMessageState recycledMessageState, Boolean[] understoodHeaders)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MtomMessageEncoder.ReadMessage(ArraySegment`1 buffer, BufferManager bufferManager, String contentType)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageEncoder.ReadMessage(Stream stream, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 maxBufferSize, String contentType)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ReadChunkedBufferedMessage(Stream inputStream)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ParseIncomingMessage(Exception&amp; requestException)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&amp; msgData, Int32 type)
at DDMEService.InterplayReference.AssetsPortType.GetChildren(GetChildrenRequest request)
at DDMEService.InterplayReference.AssetsPortTypeClient.DDMEService.InterplayReference.AssetsPortType.GetChildren(GetChildrenRequest request)
at DDMEService.InterplayReference.AssetsPortTypeClient.GetChildren(UserCredentialsType UserCredentials, GetChildrenType GetChildren1)
at DDMEService.Classes.AvidCommand.PopulateGenericAssets(String UNCHostname, String UNCDirectoryPath)
at DDMEService.Classes.CommandManager.PrepareAvidList(String HostName, String DirectoryPath, Boolean SearchSubdirectory, Boolean RenameToDirectory, String FileFilter, String ExtensionFilter, String InterplayHost, String InterplayWorkgroup, String Catalog, String LocatorSequenceStartWords, String LocatorSequenceEndWords, String Username, String Password)
at DDMEService.Classes.CommandManager.Execute()
at DDMEService.ClientHandler.ProcessCommand(String ClientIP, String Command)
at DDMEService.ClientHandler.Process(Object O)
at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallbackInternal(_ThreadPoolWaitCallback tpWaitCallBack)
at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback(Object state)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: Unrecognized message version.</ExceptionString>
</Exception>
```

**not working soap request**

```
--uuid:4475db34-2787-4220-b800-15c91678a4be+id=2
Content-ID: <http://tempuri.org/0>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8;type="text/xml"

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Header><h:UserCredentials xmlns:h="http://avid.com/interplay/ws/assets/types" xmlns="http://avid.com/interplay/ws/assets/types" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><Username>Administrator</Username><Password>avid</Password></h:UserCredentials><ActivityId CorrelationId="f29e64f8-1568-4683-b196-d53bd97a2cec" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics">13063b98-becc-416a-89ec-23a23498ed21</ActivityId></s:Header><s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><GetChildren xmlns="http://avid.com/interplay/ws/assets/types"><InterplayURI>interplay://A51WG6/Catalogs/000</InterplayURI></GetChildren></s:Body></s:Envelope>
--uuid:4475db34-2787-4220-b800-15c91678a4be+id=2--
```

**working soap request**

```
--uuid:f1481ad5-def1-42bf-a3ca-f9cff5eb856b+id=2
Content-ID: <http://tempuri.org/0>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8;type="text/xml"

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Header><h:UserCredentials xmlns:h="http://avid.com/interplay/ws/assets/types" xmlns="http://avid.com/interplay/ws/assets/types" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><Username>Administrator</Username><Password>avid</Password></h:UserCredentials></s:Header><s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><GetChildren xmlns="http://avid.com/interplay/ws/assets/types"><InterplayURI>interplay://WG5C/Catalogs/Sundance</InterplayURI></GetChildren></s:Body></s:Envelope>
--uuid:f1481ad5-def1-42bf-a3ca-f9cff5eb856b+id=2--
```

How can I properly form this to make this work against my service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why do you create the elements and then push the mtom? you already have a text encoder there so the mtom would be a second encoder. use this instead:

```
basicBinding.messageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Mtom
```

Comment: I tried this already and it still gives me this error so I am not using BindingElementCollection now

Comment: turn on WCF trace on the server to see the exact error http://blogs.msdn.com/b/madhuponduru/archive/2006/05/18/601458.aspx

Comment: if you remove the mtom on both sides does this work? also use wcf logging to see how the message looks like and publish it here. the server complains that the first line of the message is not from the correct verison.

Comment: I dont host the service.  All I know is it works with my config file

Comment: Yaron, I got this to work.  If you look at my post I had ?wsdl stuck there - I simply removed it from http://{0}/services/Assets?wsdl and it worked.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove ?wsdl from http://{0}/services/Assets?wsdl

Answer (score -1):

To create an equivalent binding in code you just need to set the properties on your BasicHttpBinding instance to the values specified in your config file.

From a quick scan through your code it looks like you can remove the code that creates the MtomMessageEncodingBindingElement instance and set the MessageEncoding property on basicBinding to Mtom.

Comment: Have you set the properties on basicBinding (for example, MessageEncoding) to be the same as the corresponding attributes in your config file?

Comment: isnt that part of the constructor MtomMessageEncodingBindingElement

Comment: You're adding the new MtomMessageEncodingBindingElement to a cloned copy of the binding elements obtained from basicBinding, not basicBinding itself. You're then passing basicBinding to the WCF proxy. As far as I know, basicBinding will have its message encoding set to text unless you configure it differently. You can do this by setting its MessageEncoding property.

Comment: already tried setting    basicBinding.MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Mtom; if that's what you mean